# How to solve flickering of image in chrome?

Tags: jquery, css, image, google-chrome, flicker

I have used this image slider built on top of jquery and jCarousel. here is the link  - http://www.midas-jewellery.com/rough/slider/slider.html

This slider works absolutely fine in IE and firefox but in chrome the images blinks once before sliding. 
Tried various tips and searched at many forums but could not get a solution.
Any help or nudge in the right direction will be highly appreciated.

Comment: I think that with examples like these, you should really try to paste these in a jsFiddle or something as this will most likely be deleted after you finish building the site and the link will be dead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

by the looks of it - your site is giving 404 message to the primary javascript files that make the slider work smooth.

http://www.midas-jewellery.com/rough/slider/jquery.jcarousel.min.js
http://www.midas-jewellery.com/rough/slider/jquery.easing.1.3.js

are both missing as well as the pagination PNG's
http://www.midas-jewellery.com/rough/images/pagination-bg.png
http://www.midas-jewellery.com/rough/images/pagination.png

try and link those up and see if that sorts out your problem